# NSTextView caret size sometimes ignored

Tags: nstextview, caret

I'm changing the caret size using `- (void)drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)aRect color:(NSColor *)aColor turnedOn:(BOOL)flag`. Anyway, when I move selection, the caret momentarily changes back to its default size.

Is there another method that draws the caret that I need to override?

*What I'm currently doing*:

```
- (void)drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)aRect color:(NSColor *)aColor turnedOn:(BOOL)flag {

    aRect.origin.y -= 1;
    aRect.origin.x -= 1;
    aRect.size.width += 1;
    aRect.size.height += 1;

    [super drawInsertionPointInRect:aRect color:aColor turnedOn:flag];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

If you're not doing it already, subclass `NSTextView` and then implement the [`drawInsertionPointInRect:color:turnedOn:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/drawInsertionPointInRect%3acolor%3aturnedOn%3a) method yourself to do the fancy caret drawing yourself.

Also pay attention to this line from the documentation:

> The focus must be locked on the receiver when this method is invoked.
>   **You should not need to invoke this method directly.**

Subclassing is the way to go.

**More application-specific answer:**

Instead of calling into `[super drawInsertionPointInRect...`, consider doing all the drawing yourself.

Something like this:

```
- (void)drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)rect color:(NSColor *)color turnedOn:(BOOL)flag
{
    //Block Cursor
    if( flag )
    {
        NSPoint aPoint=NSMakePoint( rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y+rect.size.height/2);
        int glyphIndex = [[self layoutManager] glyphIndexForPoint:aPoint inTextContainer:[self textContainer]];
        NSRect glyphRect = [[self layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(glyphIndex, 1)  inTextContainer:[self textContainer]];

        [color set ];
        rect.size.width =rect.size.height/2;
        if(glyphRect.size.width > 0 && glyphRect.size.width < rect.size.width) 
            rect.size.width=glyphRect.size.width;
        NSRectFillUsingOperation( rect, NSCompositePlusDarker);
    } else {
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:[self visibleRect] avoidAdditionalLayout:NO];
    }
}
```

(the code for which [I stole from here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/157717-nstextview-custom-cursor.html))

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually implementing that method. I updated the question. (Thanks for your answer)

Comment: Yup, tried that code already. When moving the cursor it changes back to normal

Comment: okay. I give up for now. It could be something to do with the field editor handling the caret drawing. Maybe somebody else will have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem.
Donovan's answer solves it but when I tried to draw "transparent" caret I needed more things to do and I had a solution for it.

I made a blog post for it.
http://programming.jugglershu.net/wp/?p=765

The answer for "how to draw thick and transparent caret" is ...

- Draw transparent caret in _drawInsertionPointInRect:
- Clear the caret in drawInsertionPointInRect by calling setNeedsDisplay method.

I hope this helps someone who want to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the only solution is to override the undocumented method `- (void)_drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)aRect color:(NSColor *)color`. I was hoping for a better solution, though.

Comment: Seriously you upvoted yourself when others provided the info?

Comment: @uchuugaka You mean Michael's answer? Honestly I don't understand why I created another answer to repeat just that info... weird. Thanks for pointing that out to me though.