# Glitch when drawing a custom insertion point of NSTextView

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

My question is different because the insertion point is not turning to its default representation when I move it. I have a visual issue just when my document is empty. But when the document is not empty, the insertion point looks fine.

I'm trying to draw a custom insertion point of my NSTextView subclass. And everything works fine... Except the first launch of a document. When creating a new document the first blinking of the insertion point is always glitchy. But after that first blinking everything becomes normal. Where I have to look?

```
override func drawInsertionPoint(in rect: NSRect, color: NSColor, turnedOn flag: Bool) {
    var customRect = rect
    customRect.size.width = 2.0

    if flag {
        color.set()
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor.set()
    }

    self.lockFocus()
    let path = NSBezierPath(rect:customRect)
    path.setClip()
    path.fill()
    self.unlockFocus()

    self.setNeedsDisplay(customRect, avoidAdditionalLayout: false)
}
```

And that's how it looks on the first blinking: [image]

**Update.** Removing setNeedsDisplay call makes the glitch appear all the time when the document is empty. Call of setNeedsDisplay makes the glitch appear on the empty document during the first blinking only.

The other thing I found out is that the glitch is simply a path of the default representation of the insertion point. Somehow it shows up when the document is empty. Don't understand why it happens at all.

Comment: The documentation of `drawInsertionPoint` says "The focus must be locked on the receiver when this method is invoked. You should not need to invoke this method directly."

Comment: I've been playing with those lines for a while. And if I remove setNeedsDisplay then that glitch you see on the screenshot will be there until I start typing something. setNeedsDisplay at least makes the glitch appear just once, during the first blinking only.

Comment: `flag` is always true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTextView caret size sometimes ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629356/nstextview-caret-size-sometimes-ignored)

Comment: Not at all. You should read carefully. That question is about the insertion point turns back to its default representation. My question is about the insertion point draws normally but at the first launch there's some glitch happens.

Comment: The glitch happens because the insertion point is removed in its default representation.

Comment: OK. But how can I make the glitch to disappear?

Comment: I made the customRect to have a size of the text view's visible rect. And when I saw the glitch on the full screen size text view I understood that that glitch is the default path of the insertion point. Somehow when the document is empty it became visible. But when document is not empty — everything is fine. Don't understand why it happens. But that happens only if there's no call of setNeedsDisplay. Otherwise it happens on the first blinking only.

Comment: Google found this: [nstextview+caret](https://gist.github.com/koenbok/a1b8d942977f69ff102b)

Comment: Wow! That worked, but I had to make some improvements to support rect's origin changing. I still don't know why that is happening. Maybe someday we will know something about this mystery.

Comment: Can you share your solution here?